# How do I get the MouseListener on a JTable working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, event-listener

I'm trying to get a `JTable` working with a `MouseListener`.
The code right now is a sample program for a `JTable` with Icons.
What I want is, that if you **double click** on a row, a `dialog` should open with informations from the **whole row** or just the `index-number` from the row.
But my problem is that the command: `table.addMouseListener(this);` is not working, maybe is it because of the constructor?

I tried to use a `new object` inside the main method and create then the MousListener.

```
 public class TableIcon extends JPanel
 {
   public TableIcon()
   {
       Icon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("Mypath");
       Icon addIcon = new ImageIcon("Mypath");
       Icon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("Mypath");

       String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
       Object[][] data =
       {
           {aboutIcon, "Pic1"},
           {addIcon, "Pic2"},
           {copyIcon, "Pic3"},
       };

       DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames)
       {
           public Class getColumnClass(int column)
           {
               return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
           }

           public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
           {
               return false;
           }

       };
       JTable table = new JTable( model );
       table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize
           (table.getPreferredSize());
 // ################ MyError #########
       table.addMouseListener(this); // Error
 // ##################################
       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
       add( scrollPane );  
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI()
   {
       TableIcon test = new TableIcon();

       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Icon");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.add(test);
       frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible( true );
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
       {
           public void run()
           {
               createAndShowGUI();
           }
       });
   }
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
   {
       System.out.println("clicked");
   }
}
```

In this code I expect a `print` with"clicked" but all I get is this error
**My Error**
TableIcon cannot be cast to java.awt.event.MouseListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Adapter class:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
        //Code for handling the double click event
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks!
But is the `MouseAdapter` just for a constructor or for a JTable only?

Comment: It's for JTable only

Answer (score 2):

You refer to `this` which is class `TableIcon` and it does not implement interface `MouseListener`, but method `addMouseListener()` expects it.

```java
public void addMouseListener(MouseListener l)
```

If you want to go with approach of `TableIcon` class acting as event handler as well, then add implementation for the `MouseListener` interface.

```java
public class TableIcon extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

 ...

 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // code for handling of the click event
 }

 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
 }

 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
 }

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
 }

 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
 }

}
```

Comment: If I try to implement `MouseListener` I get an error: `The type TableIcon must implement the inherited abstract method MouseListener.mouseExited(MouseEvent)`

Comment: Yes, because interface `MouseListener` prescribes 5 methods:  `mouseClicked()`, `mouseEntered()`, `mouseExited()`, `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()`. I mentioned all of them in the example provided in answer.